# Construct a new Dataframe and get the statistical summary in R Studio

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to construct a new table and get the statistical summary from the old table by each group. 
This is what I have:

```
df <- data.frame(
  number =  c(3,4,5,6,7,3,5,6,7,6),
  group= c("red", "yellow", "green", "green", "yellow", "yellow", "red", "red", "red", "green")
)
```

Please see the picture for the dataframe I want as result. Thanks ahead!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the values pretty easily with `dplyr` if you create a table with the thresholds and merge it in

```
library(dplyr)
gorder <- c("red","yellow","green")
df %>% 
  left_join(data.frame(group=gorder, thresh=c(5, 6, 2))) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(numbers=sum(number), above_thresh=sum(number>thresh), thresh=first(thresh)) 
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   group  numbers above_thresh thresh
#   <fct>    <dbl>        <int>  <dbl>
# 1 green       17            3      2
# 2 red         21            2      5
# 3 yellow      14            1      6
```

If you really need that "shape" for your output, then you can bring in `tidyr` to help reshape the output

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gorder <- c("red","yellow","green")
norder <- c("numbers", "thresh", "above_thresh")
df %>% 
  left_join(data.frame(group=gorder, thresh=c(5, 6, 2))) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(numbers=sum(number), above_thresh=sum(number>thresh), thresh=first(thresh)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-group) %>% 
  mutate(group=factor(group, levels=gorder), name=factor(name, levels=norder)) %>% 
  arrange(group, name) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=group, values_from=value)
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   name           red yellow green
#   <fct>        <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 numbers         21     14    17
# 2 thresh           5      6     2
# 3 above_thresh     2      1     3
```

Comment: It works well for the sample data. But when I apply it to my actual data, which has the same format, it gives me this error "Error: `by` required, because the data sources have no common variables". Do you know why?

Comment: It's probably the `left_join(data.frame(group=gorder, thresh=c(5, 6, 2)))`. The data frame which contains your thresholds needs to have a column name that matches the group column name in the original data.

Comment: I'm very new to R, can you please recommend a way to fix it?

Comment: I created a dataframe called threshold, which contain gorder and threshold, but the error persists. do you know how to fix? and what's the use of that left_join?

Comment: The column names should be `group` and `thresh` in this example.